# How to upgrade from cocoapods 0.33.1 to 0.35.0?

Tags: ios, upgrade, cocoapods

My Project use cocoapods 0.33.1 now and I want to update cococapods to 0.35.0,when I update my cocoapods and run pod install ,a lot of error? What is right way to upgrade cocoapods and can still work for my Project?

Comment: You will have to tell the community what type of errors you are recieving so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your current version you could just run:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

you can install a specific version of cocoa pods via the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.35.0
```

Comment: For specific user you can type: $ gem install cocoapods -v 0.35.0

Comment: To uninstall any version $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.33.1 .